# why I have to use a replacement for Mac OS X Terminal on Mac?

Tags: 14.04, command-line, compiling, mac

During my work, I use Ubuntu, but sometimes I work at home with Mac OS.
My question is following:

When I connect to the cluster (with Ubuntu) with my Mac terminal and compile package, eg. VTK, I always get ERROR like

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:61 (message):
The C compiler "/share/apps/intel/composer_xe_2013/bin/icc" is not able to compile a simple test program.
```

However, if I connect the cluster (with Ubuntu) with terminal client on Mac, e. g. MacTerm, I could compile the VTK perfectly.

Why does this happen?

Comment: Do you mean, that when you ssh to the cluster from the Mac Terminal, you get an error, but when you connect to the cluster from a linux terminal on another Ubuntu computer, you don't?

Comment: when I ssh to the cluster from the Mac Terminal and compiling some package, I get an error, but when I connect to the cluster from terminal client (MacTerm) installed on Mac, I do not.

Comment: This problem is due to that ` manpath: can't set the locale; make sure $lc_* and $lang are correct` .                                                                                        The solution is following: add the `export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8` and 
`export LANG=en_US.UTF-8` to the .bashrc file.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you are using two different ssh clients. Try login in with both of them and checking the output of the "env" command together with "echo $PATH", and compare the results. If one of the "MacTerm" environmental variables or entries in the PATH is different, set it to the same value as in the "Mac Terminal".

Comment: They are exactly same.

Comment: Just try executing "bash" and then try compiling again.

Comment: I got same error as before.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of that might change based on the terminal you use to connect would be locale-related settings (which do sometimes interfere with compiling).

Check the values of your `$LANG` or `$LC_<whatever>` environment variables (using e.g. `echo $LANG`). Sometimes setting `LANG=C` (`export LANG=C`) helps in getting things to compile (but it might mess up the output in your terminal).

Your `$TERM` variable is likely different also, but that shouldn't affect compiling.

Comment: `echo $LANG` give nothing!